# Center element in jQuery DataTable column cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This time I have a simple question.

Here there is my query results, showed in the web app using jQuery Data Table:

[image: TableNotCentered]

As you can see, the elements are not centered inside the column cells.
So, the question is: how can I show the elements, both numbers and buttons, centered?

Comment: Can you post the html and css?

Comment: text-align: center; Works also for your buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
th.dt-center, td.dt-center { text-align: center; }
```

to your css, or use Javascript

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [
       {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much.

Comment: Done just now ;)